# Python how to get length of data compressed with zlib?

Tags: python, zlib

I have a file with multiple zlib-compressed binary data, and the offsets and lengths are unknown. Below, I have a script that gets the offset of the byte after the final zlib compressed data, which is what I need. The script works; however, in order to get the length of the original zlib compressed data, I have to decompress it and re-compress it. Is there a better way to get the length without having to re-compress it? Here's my code:

```
import zlib


def inflate(infile):
    data = infile.read()
    offset = 0
    while offset < len(data):
        window = data[offset : offset + 2]
        for key, value in zlib_headers.items():
            if window == key:
                decomp_obj = zlib.decompressobj()
                yield key, offset, decomp_obj.decompress(data[offset:])
        if offset == len(data):
            break
        offset += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    zlib_headers = {b"\x78\x01": 3, b"\x78\x9c": 6, b"\x78\xda": 9}

    with open("input_file", "rb") as infile:
        *_, last = inflate(infile)

    key, offset, data = last
    start_offset = offset + len(zlib.compress(data, zlib_headers[key]))

    print(start_offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recompressing it won't even work. The recompression could be a different length. There is no assurance that the result will be the same, unless you control the compression process that made the compressed data in the first place, and you can guarantee that it uses the same compression code, same version of that code, and exactly the same settings. There is not even enough information in the zlib header to determine what the compression level was. By the way, your list of possible zlib headers is incomplete. There are 29 others it could be. The easiest and most reliable way to determine whether or not a zlib stream starts at the current byte is to begin decompressing until you either get an error or it completes. The first thing the decompressor will do is check the zlib header for validity.

To find the length of the decompressed data, feed `decomp_obj.decompress()` a fixed number of bytes at a time. E.g. 65536 bytes. Keep track of how many bytes you have fed it. Stop when `decomp_obj.eof` is true. That indicates that the end of the zlib stream has been reached. Then `decomp_obj.unused_data` will be the bytes you fed it that were after the zlib stream. Subtract the length of the leftover from your total amount fed, and you have the length of the zlib stream.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't running the decompressor at every byte a lot more inefficient than checking every byte first to see if it matches a zlib header? If so, how much more inefficient is it? If it doesn't matter too much, I suppose I could just run the decompressor at every byte, but I wasn't sure how much it mattered.

Comment: It's doing exactly the same thing you would be trying to do by hand. Checking the first two bytes for a valid zlib header. Except you know it will do it correctly, whereas your version may have (and does) have errors. There is some inefficiency in creating a new `decompressobj` every time. Unfortunately, the Python library does not expose a reset operation for the object to reuse, as the underlying zlib library does. If you really want to do it yourself, then read RFC 1950 carefully.

Comment: The other reason to try decompression directly is that two bytes may _accidentally_ be a valid zlib header, but _not_ be an actual zlib stream. You will see a valid zlib header on average every 500 bytes in randomly generated data. The decompressor will likely soon detect that it is not a valid zlib stream. Then you can move on to the next byte in your search.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help. I do have one more question, though. So trying to decompress at every byte has the same efficiency as manually checking a header match? I'm kind of confused as to what you meant by there is some inefficiency when calling the decompressobj every time. Could you explain what you meant by this? You said it's doing the same thing as manually checking the header, so what's the inefficiency?

Comment: Once a `decompressobj` either completes or fails, you can't use it again. You have to make a new one.