# Python how to iterate over reading a binary file at an offset?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to read a file starting at offset 0, then at offset 1, then at offset 2, etc. through the entire file. How would I achieve this? What would this code look like? I thought about using count from itertools, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Please show your current attempt at solving this? Do I understand correctly, you want to slice the contents of the file from the current index to to the end of the file in a loop?

Comment: Yes, I want to read the entire file, then read the entire file starting at offset 1, then offset 2, etc. I want to read the entire file with an incremental offset of 1 starting at 0, then stop when the EOF has been reached.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you will use each slice of the file? The most efficient solution will depend on how you use the data

Comment: I have an input file that I would like to try to decompress as a zlib stream, if it fails, I'd like to try the next offset, if it succeeds, I'd like to move the offset to the beginning of the unused data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976356/python-how-to-get-length-of-data-compressed-with-zlib Here you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I just need the most efficient way of trying each byte, and moving to the next offset, as well as ending at the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this should work:

```
with open('temp.bin', 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()

for i in range(len(contents)):
    print(contents[i:])
```

Instead of reading the file over and over again at offsets (using `.seek()`) it's better to load it into memory and just slice. Reading it at offsets loads it into memory either way, so it isn't more efficient and will take much longer.